# How to prevent automatically generated ID, which was created by the JSF Framework?

Tags: html, jsf

I have a question concerning the automatically generated ID, which is created by the JSF Framework. I have this JSF input component for example:

```
<h:inputText id="firstname" required="true" value="#{comedianHandler.aktuellerComedian.firstname}" />
```

This component will be transformed into this HTML code, which I can see in my webbrowser:

```
<input id="j_idt3:firstname" type="text" value="" name="j_idt3:firstname"/>
```

Is there a way to prevent the generation of the automatically ID "j_idt3"? Can I set a hard coded ID and how can I do this?

Comment: BalusC: Could you please delete this question? I have no possibilitie to delete the question, since at least one users has been answered. Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can set the id of your form to prevent automatically ID generation in this case.

```
<h:form id="formId">
```

If no ID is set, you can not prevent auto generation of an ID.